# How to Solve this Error and Execute stored procedure on Web api Core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-6.0

I tried code to execute the Stored Procedure, but I'm facing some issues on my code. help me to solve this error.

Controller

```
using Employee_API.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Employee_API.Models;
using MySqlConnector;

namespace Employee_API.Controllers
{
  [ApiController]
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class EmpController : Controller
  {

    private readonly EmpDbContext _empDbContext;

    public EmpController(EmpDbContext empDbContext)
    {

        _empDbContext = empDbContext;
    }
            
    [HttpPost("AddEmp")]    
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmp(Employee empRequest)
    {
        var name = new MySqlParameter("@Name", empRequest.Name);
        var empid = new MySqlParameter("@EmpId", empRequest.EmpId);
        var design = new MySqlParameter("@Designation", empRequest.Designation);
        var dob = new MySqlParameter("@DOB", empRequest.DOB);
        var mobile = new MySqlParameter("@Mobile", empRequest.Mobile);
        var mail = new MySqlParameter("@Mail", empRequest.Mail);

        await _empDbContext.emp_data.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC Add_New_Employee @Name, @EmpId, @Designation, @DOB, @Mobile, @Mail", name, empid, design, dob, mobile, mail).ToListAsync();

       return Ok(empRequest);

    }
  }
}
```

DbContext

```
using Employee_API.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Employee_API.Data
{
  public class EmpDbContext : DbContext
  {
    public EmpDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> emp_data { get; set; } 
   }  
 }
```

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cfDo.png)

[[image: Error On My code]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN8Qo.png)

I've tried on many online search, but I couldn't find any solution for this code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you share your error message into your question not image? According to the error message, what's your `ExecuteSqlRaw`?

Comment: It would be great if you could share your code snippet instead of screenshot.

Comment: Do  you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`?

Comment: Post the code and error as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested.

Comment: In any case you don't need an ORM like Entity Framework to execute stored procedures. An ORM is used to Map Objects to Relational data.

Comment: I updated my code also, please help me to solve this issue. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running raw SQL is quite the opposite of  what's EntityFramework for.

In your code, you're calling `ExecureSqlRaw` against `DBSet`, but you should execute it against `Database`, like this

```
_empDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("...")
```